# Change legend on ggplot

Tags: r

```
time<- as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-10 20:51:53.103","2014-12-10 20:56:54.204","2014-12-10 20:57:54.204"), tz= "GMT")
p<-c(49.32, 60,50)
s<-c("B","","S")
pointcolor<-c("green","black","red")
share<-c(35,0,6)
pointsize<-c(10,5,10)
shapeType<-c(16,10,16)
bigDF<-data.frame(time=time, p=p, s=s, pointcolor=pointcolor, share=share, pointsize=pointsize, shapeType=shapeType)
bigDF
#ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + 
 # geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType), 
  #                size = as.factor(pointsize),
   #               color = pointcolor)) +
  #scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "green", "red")) +
  #scale_size_manual(values = 10)

ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType),
                  size = as.factor(pointsize), 
                  colour = pointcolor)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = levels(as.factor(bigDF$pointcolor))   )
```

when you plot it you will see:

[image]

I want to remove the shapetype and pointsize legends so I do:

add these 2 to the graph:

```
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType),
                  size = as.factor(pointsize), 
                  colour = pointcolor)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = levels(as.factor(bigDF$pointcolor))   )+ scale_shape_identity(guide="none") + scale_size_identity(guide="none")
```

I get an error:

```
Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

this is due to scale_size_identity(guide="none"). Do you know how to remove the pointsize legend?

Also - Do you know how to change the color legend so that instead of reading black, green, red it will say only "Buy" for green and "Sell" for red?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
levels(bigDF$pointcolor) <- c(NA, "Buy", "Sell")

ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType),
                    size = as.factor(pointsize), 
                    colour = pointcolor)) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Status", values = c("Sell" = "red", "Buy" = "green"))+ scale_shape_discrete(guide=FALSE) + scale_size_discrete(guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @RStudent! I am trying to only have the legend say the "BUy" or "Sell" so I did  scale_color_manual(values = levels(as.factor(bigDF$PointColor)) , labels= c("","Buy","Sell")  )  but the black dot still appears.  And do you also know to change the title of the legend?  From "PointColor" to "Status"? Thank you!